# How can I create this column that gives back a list when multiple options are true?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In this example, I would like for each row to buy the car with the maximum speed, given that it has brakes (if both don't have brakes, they are equally appealing).

```
import pandas as pd

ExampleOfWhatIHave = {'Car51-speed':[1, 200, 19, 18],
        'Car52-speed':[20, 21, 19, 18],
       'Car51-brakes':[True, True, False, False],
        'Car52-brakes':[True, True, False, True]}

ExampleOfWhatINeed = {'Car51-speed':[1, 200, 19, 180],
        'Car52-speed':[20, 21, 19, 18],
       'Car51-brakes':[True, True, False, False],
        'Car52-brakes':[True, True, False, True],
           'Cartobuy': [['Car52'],['Car51'],['Car52','Car51'],['Car52']]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(ExampleOfWhatINeed)
```

Please imagine the number of cars and variables to be very large in reality (hence 51, 52), so the '-' is the meaningful distinction you can use to loop over them, not the index (I intentionally made it simpler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
speeds = df.filter(regex=r"speed$")
mask = df.filter(regex=r"brakes$")

x = speeds.mul(mask.values)
x["max"] = x.max(axis=1)
df["cartobuy"] = x.apply(
    lambda x: [
        i.split("-")[0] for i, val in zip(x.index, x[:-1]) if val == x["max"]
    ],
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Car51-speed  Car52-speed  Car51-brakes  Car52-brakes        Cartobuy
0            1           20          True          True         [Car52]
1          200           21          True          True         [Car51]
2           19           19         False         False  [Car52, Car51]
3          180           18         False          True         [Car52]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```py
# Mask Brake Logic
brake_m = df.filter(regex='speed$').values * df.filter(regex='brakes$').values
# Get Unique Cars List
cars = np.unique(np.array(df.columns.str.split('-').tolist())[:, 0])
# Mask Speed Logic on Max
speed_m = pd.DataFrame((brake_m == np.amax(brake_m, axis=1)[:, None]),
                       columns=cars)
# Aggregate to List
df['cartobuy'] = speed_m.agg(lambda s: list(s.index[s]), axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
   Car51-speed  Car52-speed  Car51-brakes  Car52-brakes        cartobuy
0            1           20          True          True         [Car52]
1          200           21          True          True         [Car51]
2           19           19         False         False  [Car51, Car52]
3           18           18         False          True         [Car52]
```

---

Explaination:

Mask over speeds with brake values:

`brake_m`

```
[[  1  20]
 [200  21]
 [  0   0]
 [  0  18]]
```

Then mask over speed values based on the max value (to keep if multiple max values)

`cars`:

```
['Car51' 'Car52']
```

`speed_m`

```
   Car51  Car52
0  False   True
1   True  False
2   True   True
3  False   True
```

Then agg rows into lists and assign back to DataFrame:

```
speed_m.agg(lambda s: list(s.index[s]), axis=1)
```

```
0           [Car52]
1           [Car51]
2    [Car51, Car52]
3           [Car52]
dtype: object
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ExampleOfWhatIHave = {'Car51-speed': [1, 200, 19, 18],
                      'Car52-speed': [20, 21, 19, 18],
                      'Car51-brakes': [True, True, False, False],
                      'Car52-brakes': [True, True, False, True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ExampleOfWhatIHave)

brake_m = df.filter(regex='speed$').values * df.filter(regex='brakes$').values
cars = np.unique(np.array(df.columns.str.split('-').tolist())[:, 0])
speed_m = pd.DataFrame((brake_m == np.amax(brake_m, axis=1)[:, None]),
                       columns=cars)
df['cartobuy'] = speed_m.agg(lambda s: list(s.index[s]), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me an error though...
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U5'), dtype('<U5')) -> dtype('<U5')

Comment: Being able to multiply a list by a boolean dataframe like that is one of the newest pandas features. Updated my answer to be more backwards compatible.